# Why sometimes no detail info when debugging java code on eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, spring-roo

Sometimes when I debug in eclipse, move the mouse on the parameter, no debug info like value and something else displayed but description of the parameter like the pic follow:

Sample is the aspectJ .aj source code I debugged.
Anyone can tell me why sometimes no detail info and how to fix it?

[image: Debug .aj file in eclipse]

Comment: If you have the choice, I recommend trying out intelliJ (http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/).  Here is a comparison of the two (http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/01/intellij-vs-eclipse.html).  (I have personally struggled days with eclipse's debugger and switching to intellij solved my issue in about 10 minutes.  This isn't exactly an answer to your question, though. ;))

Answer (score 0):

This could be an AspectJ specific issue: try installing the [AspectJ Development Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/) for Eclipse and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but not only aspectj, this issue keep appears when debugs some other codes. Maybe related to thread?

Comment: Ah, if it is happening elsewhere then it may very well be thread-related. I see similar issues from time to time debugging Android apps: I get a JDI error message and no variable detail shows in the tooltip. Haven't found a fix to it, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution. Whenever you run into this issue, Go to debug perspective. You will see thread will selected as parent process. Change the thread selection. Assign it to the thread which says Suspended as has your breakpoint line number. By doing you will get back all your debug values and debug commands like step into , step over etc.